# Enable root to console login only and restrict ssh login for root only

Tags: ssh, login, ubuntu-14.04, root

I want to enable root login at the console only, and disable root login via SSH.

However other users can still SSH to the server (Ubuntu 14) and even sudo if there part of the sudoers group.

I have the sudo bit sorted, just not sure how to restrict root to console login only.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, set `PermitRootLogin` to

```
 PermitRootLogin no
```

and restart the sshd daemon:

```
service ssh restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PermitRootLogin no
```